# Why does the std::copy_if signature not constrain the predicate type

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

Imagine we have the following situation:

```
struct A
{
    int i;
};

struct B
{
    A a;
    int other_things;
};

bool predicate( const A& a)
{
    return a.i > 123;
}

bool predicate( const B& b)
{
    return predicate(b.a);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< A > a_source;
    std::vector< B > b_source;

    std::vector< A > a_target;
    std::vector< B > b_target;

    std::copy_if(a_source.begin(), a_source.end(), std::back_inserter( a_target ), predicate);
    std::copy_if(b_source.begin(), b_source.end(), std::back_inserter( b_target ), predicate);

    return 0;
}
```

Both the call to `std::copy_if` generate a compile error, because the correct overload of `predicate()` function cannot be infered by the compiler since the `std::copy_if` template signature accepts any type of predicate:

```
template<typename _IIter, 
         typename _OIter, 
         typename _Predicate>
_OIter copy_if( // etc...
```

I found the overload resolution working if I wrap the `std::copy_if` call into a more constrained template function:

```
template<typename _IIter, 
         typename _OIter, 
         typename _Predicate = bool( const typename std::iterator_traits<_IIter>::value_type& ) >
void copy_if( _IIter source_begin, 
              _IIter source_end, 
              _OIter target,  
              _Predicate pred)
{
    std::copy_if( source_begin, source_end, target, pred );
}
```

My question is: why in the STL is it not already constrained like this? From what I've seen, if the `_Predicate` type is not a function that returns `bool` and accepts the iterated input type, it is going to generate a compiler error anyway. So why not putting this constrain already in the signature, so that overload resolution can work?

Comment: Your constraint is too strong (`const` not required, some conversion are allowed (`int` to `bool`)). `decltype` would allow correct requirement (or Concept), but that method was done before c++11.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the predicate does not have to be a function, but it can be a functor too. And restricting functor type is close to impossible since it can be anything at all as long as it has `operator()` defined.

Actually I suggest you convert the overloaded function to a polymorphic functor here:

```
struct predicate {
    bool operator()( const A& a) const
    {
        return a.i > 123;
    }

    bool operator()( const B& b) const
    {
        return operator()(b.a);
    }
}
```

and call the functor with an instance, i.e.

```
std::copy_if(a_source.begin(), a_source.end(), std::back_inserter( a_target ), predicate());
std::copy_if(b_source.begin(), b_source.end(), std::back_inserter( b_target ), predicate());
//                                                                                      ^^ here, see the ()
```

Then the correct overload will be selected inside the algorithm.

Comment: This is very interesting. Two questions: (1) why in this case the correct overload is selected? (2) is it possible to make the `operator()` static?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108, ad (1), the template now gets both overloads in a package and the selection happens deep inside the template where there is actually enough information to do it. Ad (2), yes, it should be, but it does not make much difference as you need to create the dummy instance anyway.

Comment: And, indeed, lambdas are defined in terms of function objects, and only non-capturing lambdas have conversion to function pointer defined (you have to store the captured values somewhere!)

Comment: @JohannesD non-capturing non-`auto` lambdas that is.

Comment: @Yakk Right, indeed. I only thought about C++11 as the question didn't have a C++14 tag.

Answer (score 5):

This problem does not only affect predicates to algorithms. It occurs anywhere that template type deduction deduces an overloaded function. Template type deduction happens before overload resolution, so the compiler lacks the contextual information to resolve the ambiguity.

The correctly written constraint would be hideously complex, as it would need to take into account argument and return type conversions, binds, lambdas, functors, `mem_fn`s and so on.

An easy way to solve the ambiguity (IMHO) is to call the predicate through a lambda.

```
std::copy_if(a_source.begin(), a_source.end(), 
         std::back_inserter( a_target ), 
         [](auto&& x){ return predicate(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)); });
```

This defers overload resolution until after template type deduction.

> What if I refuse (or my boss refuses) to upgrade to c++14

Then hand-roll the same lambda:

```
struct predicate_caller
{
  template<class T>
  decltype(auto) operator()(T&& t) const 
  {
    return predicate(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
};
```

and call like so:

```
std::copy_if(b_source.begin(), b_source.end(), 
             std::back_inserter( b_target ), 
             predicate_caller());
```

Comment: This, however, only works with C++14 generic lambdas. Which is new enough that it might not be available at your local compiler yet.

Comment: @JanHudec I can't think of a c++11 compiler for which there is no painless upgrade to c++14. My view is that staying with c++11 is itself an anti pattern. However, a function object with templated call operator will suffice.

Comment: @JanHudec hand-rolled templated functor provided for all the die-hards out there.